# Oracle Wallet creation - what does the option -wrl stand for?

Tags: oracle, oracle-wallet

Please let me know what could this option (-wrl) stand for in relation to this Oracle wallet creation. This would help me to have a mental map what wrl means.

Sample command:
mkstore -wrl <wallet_location> -createCredential wallet-alias scott tiger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [the `v$encryption_wallet view`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/V-ENCRYPTION_WALLET.html#GUID-054B6FBC-4263-4A91-AEBD-D6FB50C22107) column names and descriptions, it's probably fair to assume it stands for "wallet resource locator".

[The glossary](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbimi/glossary.html#GUID-4FCC8F80-9CBF-4041-8C8F-4E2A650DE201) seems to back that up:

> **Wallet Resource Locator**
>
> A wallet resource locator (WRL) provides all necessary information to locate a wallet. It is a path to an operating system directory that contains a wallet.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer ...that totally make sense!